# ASP.NEW MVC3 Ajax BeginForm not sending as Ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am experiencing the same problem as many people have asked about before, where Ajax.BeginForm is not sending the call as ajax, i.e. Request.IsAjaxRequest() == false, but not had any luck with the suggested solutions (missing js files, set 'UnobtrusiveJavascript' etc.)

My _**Layout.cshtml** file looks like this:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Web.config**

```
<add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

**View**

```
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AjaxTest", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" }))
            {
                <button class="btn" onclick="this.form.submit();">Hit Me!</button>
            }
            <div id="result"></div>
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AjaxTest(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        bool isAjax = Request.IsAjaxRequest();
        return Content("Hello World");
    }
```

I have run it through Firebug and don't get any errors.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are submitting the form yourself using `onclick="this.form.submit()"`.

Remove that bit. At least give a chance to AjaxForm to show some colors :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you should have that code in the onclick. Just set the button type to be submit